# Use SemanticZoom to show alphabetized headers like on the Start Menu

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a collection of items that I want to display in an alphabetized list where you can click on a header to get a zoomed out view that shows a GridView with the letters a-z (plus a few more) like on the Start Menu. I'm guessing I should use a SemanticZoom but I'm not sure how to set it up. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to provide a zoomedin and zoomedout view in your xaml.
You'll also need to group your data and provide a 'key' ( the first character of each word ) so that the `jumplist`can use that for it's overview.

For reference the boilerplate xaml:

```
<SemanticZoom>
     <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
         <!-- Element to display when "zoomed in". Usually a ListView or GridView -->
     </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
     <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
         <!-- Element for jump list, usually a GrivView or ListView -->
     </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
 </SemanticZoom>
```

A complete example can be found here: http://visuallylocated.com/post/2014/04/28/Migrating-from-the-LongListSelector-to-the-ListView-in-Windows-Phone-XAML-Apps.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the example.